# Avoid onMeasure and onLayout everytime ImageView Bitmap is set

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, view, imageview

This is my setup. I have a custom `ListView` with some fancy headers, which is inside a `ViewPager`. I'm maintaining a memory cache of images that having been downloaded and stored locally like any self-respecting developer would.

The issue I'm having is that everytime I call `setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)` on the `ImageView` in my `ListView`'s `getView()` method, using a Bitmap from the cache, it's causing my all Views to `onMeasure()`. I've looked through the Android `ImageView` source code and found this:

```
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != drawable) {
        mResource = 0;
        mUri = null;

        int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
        int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;

        updateDrawable(drawable);

        if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
            requestLayout();
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

So I can see that `setImageDrawable` (which is called by `setImageBitmap`) requests its layout whenever the `drawable` has differing dimensions than its previous `Drawable`. The problem is that my `ImageView` is set static to 60dp x 60dp, so its size isn't going to change regardless of the size of its image.

Is there a way I can get around the layouts being constantly remeasured as I scroll? The `onMeasure` and `onLayout` calls are propagating their way up the `View` tree, so my `ListView` and `ViewPager` are also getting measured in the middle of the list scrolling, which is obviously causing serious performance issues (~100ms UI jumps).

The performance is awful and I need to correct it. Anyone have any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: mind sharing how you fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while but I have a similar issue recently, one row in my listview's height changed too much, causing the listview.onmeasure called.

If you are build against API-14 and above, you can set breakpoint in the SDK source code. that should help to figure out why height is changed.